# Package operation failed when updating 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, updates, package-management, dpkg

Whenever I try to update 12.04, I get the "**Package Operation Failed**" message. I haven't been able to update my system. In the "**Details**" section it says:

```
installArchives() failed:  
Extracting templates from packages: 30%% Extracting templates from packages: 61%% 
Extracting templates from packages: 91%% Extracting templates from packages: 100%% 
Preconfiguring packages ...

Extracting templates from packages: 30%% 
Extracting templates from packages: 61%% 
Extracting templates from packages: 91%% 
Extracting templates from packages: 100%% 
Preconfiguring packages ...

Extracting templates from packages: 30%% 
Extracting templates from packages: 61%% 
Extracting templates from packages: 91%% 
Extracting templates from packages: 100%% 
Preconfiguring packages ...

Extracting templates from packages: 30%% 
Extracting templates from packages: 61%% 
Extracting templates from packages: 91%% 
Extracting templates from packages: 100%% 
Preconfiguring packages ... 

dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 42150 package 'x11-apps':  blank line in value of field 'Description' Error in function:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/dpkg/info/pppconfig*
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq pppconfig
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pppconfig
```

[**Source**](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/209713)

Comment: Please mark your answer as correct if it solves the problem.